# Ant-сборка проекта в Eclipse с подключением .dll

Tags: java, ant, lwjgl

Я пишу игру на Java с использованием 2D движка [Slick2D](http://slick.ninjacave.com/).
В Eclipse IDE проект работает штатно, а при сборке и запуске через File>Export в Runnable JAR File дальше главного меню, написанного на Swing дело не идёт - явно не загружаются нативные библиотеки.
Не смотря на то, что все .jar и .dll библиотеки в архиве наличествовали, а под рукой вроде [было](https://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/technogrette/soft/eclipse-ant/) пару туториалов, попытки вручную прописать их в  manifest/build.xml/classpath на разных стадиях сборки позорно провалились.
Пробовал загружать их в исходном коде через:

`System.loadLibrary("lwjgl");`

или

```
File lib1 = new File("lib/windows/lwjgl.dll");  
System.load(lib1.getAbsolutePath());
```

Опять же - в IDE работает как часы, а Runnable JAR уже нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашлось в книге [Slick2D Game Development](http://93.174.95.27/ads.php?md5=91d3fc7aa0db2351a17afc243492c57e), которую мне удалось скачать в глубинах сети.
Им стала программа [JarSplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice), которая собирает проект.
How2Use:

- Сначала необходимо создать НЕ-запускаемый JAR-файл.
  (В моём случае потребовалось исключить из сборки lwjgl.jar, slick.jar, jinput.jar и .classpath, иначе возникала ошибка появления дубликата при сборке)
- На вкладке Add Jars добавить свой jar из п.1, и необходимые библиотеки.
  (В моём случае, как раз те, которые я исключил в п.1. Если их не исключить из сборки в IDE, но и не добавлять при сборке в JarSplice, проект работать не будет)
- На вкладке Add Natives добавить нативные библиотеки
- На вкладке (кто бы мог подумать!..) Main Class прописать главный класс
- Создать, собственно, конечный jar-файл